# Como puedo evitar � cuando se imprime en pantala

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Hola cuando paso los datos me aparecen siempre estos iconos:

�What is Html?
Html es un lenguaje de programaci�n para poder crear p�ginas web...

como puedo evitarlo por favor.

Todos los datos siempre me aparecen de esa forma.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base). El problema ha sido tratado con amplitud en la [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967).

Comment: Si deseas realizar otra pregunta lo puedes hacer, no hay necesidad de cambiar todo el contenido de esta

Comment: Esque estoy bloqueado por que piensan que estaba duplicada

Answer (score 1):

El problema cuando aparecen ese tipo de caracteres extraños, son siempre los juegos de caracteres. Te recomiendo que sigas en [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%C3%A1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base) que te pusieron en los comentarios.

Creo que en tu caso concreto lo que ocurre es que introduces datos directamente en **phpMyAdmin** y cuando generas el HTML a partir de esos datos aparecen los caracteres que mencionas. Puedes probar otras herramientas para gestionar tu BD y te ocurriría lo mismo (haz una búsqueda de: "alternativas a phpMyAdmin"), seguramente la más utilizada es [adminer](https://www.adminer.org).

La solución habitual es seleccionar el juego de caracteres adecuado a nivel de base de datos y a nivel de tabla, aunque creo que esto no resuelve el problema al introducir directamente los datos en phpmyadmin, lo que no será la opción habitual en una aplicación real.

Una configuración habitual al crear una nueva base de datos sería seleccionar el "Cotejamiento": **utf8_general_ci**

y a nivel de tabla, cuando se crean, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ciudades` (
    id          int(9)          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre      varchar(255)    NOT NULL,

        PRIMARY KEY (id)) 
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```